# Durations over 24 hours become datetime.datetime instead of datetime.TIME. For example "24:35:23" turns into "1900-01-01 00:35:23"?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

Excel file has three columns. The first two have datetimes and the third one has durations:

```
start               end                   duration
2019-03-31 11:44:58 2019-03-31 12:39:03   0:54:05
2019-03-31 11:42:32 2019-03-31 14:05:35   2:23:03
2019-03-31 11:37:24 2019-03-31 17:04:26   5:27:02
2019-03-30 16:57:59 2019-03-31 17:33:22   24:35:23
2019-03-31 14:34:09 2019-03-31 18:01:01   3:26:52
```

However, when I read this file into a pandas dataframe, the value that is over 24 hours gets messed up:

```
df.head()
        start                 end                      duration
5096    2019-03-31 11:44:58   2019-03-31 12:39:03      00:54:05
5097    2019-03-31 11:42:32   2019-03-31 14:05:35      02:23:03
5098    2019-03-31 11:37:24   2019-03-31 17:04:26      05:27:02
5099    2019-03-30 16:57:59   2019-03-31 17:33:22      1900-01-01 00:35:23
5100    2019-03-31 14:34:09   2019-03-31 18:01:01      03:26:52
```

The type of the correct values in "duration" column is `datetime.time`, but the "1900-01-01 00:35:23" (that is supposed to be "24:35:23") has now become `datetime.datetime`.

The question: **how do I prevent the "24:35:23" and other values over 24 hours from becoming datetime.datetime and getting messed up like that?**

Later I would like to transform the values in "duration" column into type timedelta, but the values should be in form of %H:%M:%S for that to succeed.

Comment: How are you reading it? `pd.read_csv()` ?

Comment: @harvpan simply pd.read_excel(f"data/{file}", sheet_name = "F", skipfooter = 1, decimal = ".")

Comment: try passing `dtype={'duration':'timedelta64[ns]'}` or something similar to `read_excel`.

Comment: I'm getting a "ValueError: Unable to convert column duration to type timedelta64[ns]"

Comment: I don't know that `pandas` would do that conversion with the code you provided. But the simple solution is to just make it a `timedelta` after reading in the file `df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.duration)` Date/time parsing is typically complicated enough that it's best to do it manually after the read instead of trying to parse when reading. It typically fails on most messy data anyway.

Comment: @ALollz that is actually what I'm trying to do, but I'm getting a "TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len() ...... ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar:", and assumed that it's because the column has both datetime.time and datetime.datetime types

Comment: @KMFR then I'd say read in the file with `dtype={'duration': str}`. I'm surprised `pandas` is doing such a conversion in the first place. On the other hand `.xlsx` files are complicated, so what you see may not be what is stored. Excel has a lot of formatting going on. If that doesn't work I suggest you save the sheet as a plain `.csv` which would make seeing the underlying data easier, and should help in debugging.

Comment: @ALollz Now that you mentioned, I noticed the Excel file does indeed have lots of equations etc. In this case I can just take pd.to_timedelta(df.end - df.start) and ignore the original duration column. Thanks!